# Create INSERT INTO from SELECT in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.5

How to create `INSERT INTO` statements, using `SELECT` statement? I need it because I want to delete 10k of records from a table, but if someday some of that record need to be restored I want to do that easily. I don't want to backup the whole table, because I just need to restore some of deleted rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pg_dump` with the `--inserts` option. You should also check the manual of your SQL client. Some can export data as `INSERT` statements.

Another option is to just copy the rows that you delete into a new table:

```
create table _backup
as
with deleted as (
  delete from the_table 
  where .... --<< put your condition here
  returning *
)
select  *
from deleted;
```

The above will delete rows from `the_table` and all rows that are deleted are copied into the table `_backup`

Answer (score 7):

If you really needs the insert statement using a query:

```
   select 'INSERT INTO table values ('||bla_integer||', '''||bla_string||''')'
   from thetable; 

   Where bla_string and bla_integer are example columns from thetable...
```

Comment: Code that writes code!